# Is it possible to use an indexed iterator to access the index of another array?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I'm trying to use an iterator constructed as a `std::vector<std::array<int,3>>::iterator` data type in a loop to access the index of a std::array, but whenever I dereference and index the iterator I'm getting the error "no operator "*" matches these operands". What can I do to fix this?

```
std::vector<std::array<int,3>> x = {{0,1,2},{5,1,6}};
std::vector<std::array<int,3>>::iterator it;
std::array<int, 1000> y;
for (it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++) {
     if (y[*it[0]] == 0){
          do something;
     }
```

Comment: i think the problem is that subscript (`[]`) has higher precedence than dereference (`*`), that said I would encourage you to use a range for loop (`for (const auto& v : x) { }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precedence of `[]` is higher than that of `*` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

You need to write `(*it)[0]`.

As a side note, using a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) or
[`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) (`std::for_each()`,
`std::transform()`, `std::find_if()`...) is less error-prone
than dealing explicitly with the iterators (or indices)
in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as @prog-fh and @Borgleader suggest, you need to use parentheses to clarify which operator applies to what.

I'll note that if you can use C++20, you can write your code this way:

```
using triplet = std::array<int,3>;
std::vector<triplet> x = {{0,1,2},{5,1,6}};
std::array<int, 1000> y;
// initialize y somehow...
auto filter_by_y = [&y](const triplet& tr) { return y[tr[0]] == 0; }

for (const auto& triplet : x | std::views::filter(filter_by_y) ) {
   do_something(triplet);
}
```

and now there are *no* `if`'s and no raw loops in your code. You can read more about [filter-views](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm pretty new to programming, this is a lot to make sense of so sorry if I'm asking a dumb question. But, the sample code you provided is a different approach than using the range-for loop that @prog-fh suggested right?

Comment: @NickC: It's going another step beyond using the ranged-for loop. Actually, the "for (foo : bar)" syntax should let you know that this also has a ranged-for loop - but instead of ranging over x, it ranges over a "filtered view" of x - just those elements of x with the appropriate y value being 0.